# Braintree library requires open_ssl extension when test with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, braintree

I am working Testcase in phpunit for payment library of braintree it gives Braintree library requires open_ssl extension when test with phpunit

Comment: Yes it means you need to enable `openssl` extension in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

Find the **php.ini** file and find the line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

And then restart your server.

Comment: On mac/linux it should be  openssl.so for the file name. If you are using AMPPS or a similar stack, there should be an option to turn on a specific extension from the php section of the program, which will take care of writing that line in the php.ini file for you.